# Dynamic Bash Aliases

Tags: bash, eval, alias

I'm trying to dynamically define my aliases, but i must be doing something wrong..

I have a file called hosts.txt. here is the format:

```
#shortname,host,account
h1,host1.somewhere.com,acc1
h2,host2.somewhere.com,acc1
h3,host3.somewhere.com,acc1
```

in my bash_profile I have the following code

```
grep -v '^#' hosts.txt | while read line;do
    DATA=(${line//,/ })
    cmd="${DATA[0]}=\"ssh ${DATA[2]}@${DATA[1]}\""
    eval $cmd
done
```

when I login I would then expect to see my aliases defined as follow

```
alias h1=ssh acc1@hos1
alias h2=ssh acc1@hos2
alias h3=ssh acc1@hos3
```

but I don't any idea how to achieve this?

**Resovled proper way:**
Alias can't be dynamicaly defined using the while loop as it runs in subshell, so what it defines never makes us to the parent shell. that's what the question was about.. 
Once I moved that the the forloop it worked just fine.

Comment: Where is the word "alias" in your bash_profile?

Comment: This seems like a terrible way to do what you are trying to do here. A single function which uses an array seems like a much better idea to me.

Comment: Just to point the security hole here -- if someone can modify hosts.txt, they could easily insert whatever commands they want in there and do whatever they want to your system.   `eval` is considered evil for that reason.

Comment: In the script I have it

cmd="alias ${DATA[0]}=\"ssh ${DATA[2]}@${DATA[1]}\""

Comment: @John But sometimes there's no other way round... Like in this case.

Comment: `alias` is already a command whose arguments undergo parameter expansion. `alias ${DATA[0]}="ssh ${DATA[2]}@${DATA[1]}"` would be sufficient; there's no need for `eval` here.

Comment: Sure there's a way around -- make sure no-one can modify hosts.txt or run in a very limited account, check for semicolons in DATA[0], etc.   I'm just pointing out that this solution has a security vulnerability associated with it, and it should be taken into account.

Comment: @4ae1e1 This is not one of those cases.

Comment: @chepner You're right, you doesn't need to use eval here. But that doesn't really address the security aspect, which is what I was commenting against.

Comment: In fact, if someone can modify `hosts.txt`, then they can probably modify `~/.ssh/config` or shell runcoms as well. `eval` is just easier to screw up (say, with a malformatted `hosts.txt`) and looks worse. No real security gain by not using `eval`.

Comment: Not true; `ssh` only works if `.ssh/config` is writable *only* by the user. If you're very careful, you can minimize the security risk when using `eval`, but you can eliminate an entire source of risk by *not* using it, and in this case, you aren't losing *any* functionality by avoiding it.

Answer (score 3):

The `ssh` config file can already define host name aliases that do essentially what you are trying to do. In `~/.ssh/config`, add

```
Host h1
    HostName host1.somewhere.com
    User acc1

Host h2
    HostName host2.somewhere.com
    User acc1

Host h3
    HostName host3.somewhere.com
    User acc1
```

Then you can just type `ssh h1` as a shortcut for `ssh acc1@host1.somewhere.com`. If you *really* still need a shorter alias, just add the following to your `.bash_profile` as well.

```
for h in h1 h2 h3; do
    alias $h="ssh $h"
done
```

For something that you only need to type once in the two configuration files, it's not really worth trying to automate any further. Just hard-code them. If you must, though:

```
while read _ host; do
    alias $host="ssh $host"
done < <(grep "Host " ~/.ssh/config)
```

Comment: the question was how to add dynamic aliases and as example I added extract how to add ssh alias.

Comment: In general, you don't need `eval` to create an dynamic alias, as I've shown. The arguments are already expanded by the shell before `alias` is actually called.